# re.findall() returns extra data when using optionals in between Regex expressions

Tags: python

I seem to be getting additional variables that I do not want stored into this array. What I expected to return after running the following code is this

```
[('999-999-9999'), ('999 999 9999'), ('999.999.9999')]
```

However what I end up with is the following

```
[('999-999-9999', '-', '-'), ('999 999 9999', ' ', ' '), ('999.999.9999', '.', '.')]
```

The following is what I have

```
teststr = '''
    Phone: 999-999-9999,
           999 999 9999,
           999.999.9999
'''
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'(\d{3}(-|\s|\.)\d{3}(-|\s|\.)\d{4})')

regexMatches = phoneRegex.findall(teststr)
print(regexMatches)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the inner capturing groups to non-capturing groups.

```
(?:-|\s|\.)
```

or

```
[-\s.]
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> teststr = '''
    Phone: 999-999-9999,
           999 999 9999,
           999.999.9999
'''
>>> re.findall(r'\b(\d{3}[-.\s]\d{3}[.\s-]\d{4})\b', teststr)
['999-999-9999', '999 999 9999', '999.999.9999']
>>>
```